# Magento 2 PWA: Direct Links are not working in PWA

Tags: pwa, pwa-studio, upward

I have created multiple cms pages I have added links in the footer,
but if I open cms pages directly from the url it shows the error, something went wrong.

if I define CMS page identifier in `venia-upward.yml` file it works but its manual process, but is there any way to automate this?